# Stacked bar chart using Gnuplot via Lualatex

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, luatex, gnuplot

when I make `sin(x)` in gnuplot and compile it via Lualatex it does work, but when I make stacked bar chart in gnuplot, and do the same, now it does not work. I am using `\input{filename.tex}` with `graphicx` package. Disclaimer - I am new with gnuplot.
This is source code for `sin(x)`:

```
% GNUPLOT: LaTeX picture with Postscript
\begingroup
  \makeatletter
  \providecommand\color[2][]{%
    \GenericError{(gnuplot) \space\space\space\@spaces}{%
      Package color not loaded in conjunction with
      terminal option `colourtext'%
    }{See the gnuplot documentation for explanation.%
    }{Either use 'blacktext' in gnuplot or load the package
      color.sty in LaTeX.}%
    \renewcommand\color[2][]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\includegraphics[2][]{%
    \GenericError{(gnuplot) \space\space\space\@spaces}{%
      Package graphicx or graphics not loaded%
    }{See the gnuplot documentation for explanation.%
    }{The gnuplot epslatex terminal needs graphicx.sty or graphics.sty.}%
    \renewcommand\includegraphics[2][]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\rotatebox[2]{#2}%
  \@ifundefined{ifGPcolor}{%
    \newif\ifGPcolor
    \GPcolorfalse
  }{}%
  \@ifundefined{ifGPblacktext}{%
    \newif\ifGPblacktext
    \GPblacktexttrue
  }{}%
  % define a \g@addto@macro without @ in the name:
  \let\gplgaddtomacro\g@addto@macro
  % define empty templates for all commands taking text:
  \gdef\gplbacktext{}%
  \gdef\gplfronttext{}%
  \makeatother
  \ifGPblacktext
    % no textcolor at all
    \def\colorrgb#1{}%
    \def\colorgray#1{}%
  \else
    % gray or color?
    \ifGPcolor
      \def\colorrgb#1{\color[rgb]{#1}}%
      \def\colorgray#1{\color[gray]{#1}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LTw\endcsname{\color{white}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LTb\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LTa\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT0\endcsname{\color[rgb]{1,0,0}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT1\endcsname{\color[rgb]{0,1,0}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT2\endcsname{\color[rgb]{0,0,1}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT3\endcsname{\color[rgb]{1,0,1}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT4\endcsname{\color[rgb]{0,1,1}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT5\endcsname{\color[rgb]{1,1,0}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT6\endcsname{\color[rgb]{0,0,0}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT7\endcsname{\color[rgb]{1,0.3,0}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT8\endcsname{\color[rgb]{0.5,0.5,0.5}}%
    \else
      % gray
      \def\colorrgb#1{\color{black}}%
      \def\colorgray#1{\color[gray]{#1}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LTw\endcsname{\color{white}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LTb\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LTa\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT0\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT1\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT2\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT3\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT4\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT5\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT6\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT7\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT8\endcsname{\color{black}}%
    \fi
  \fi
    \setlength{\unitlength}{0.0500bp}%
    \ifx\gptboxheight\undefined%
      \newlength{\gptboxheight}%
      \newlength{\gptboxwidth}%
      \newsavebox{\gptboxtext}%
    \fi%
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.5pt}%
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{1pt}%
\begin{picture}(7200.00,5040.00)%
    \gplgaddtomacro\gplbacktext{%
      \csname LTb\endcsname%%
      \put(726,440){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}$-1$}}%
      \put(726,878){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}$-0.8$}}%
      \put(726,1316){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}$-0.6$}}%
      \put(726,1754){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}$-0.4$}}%
      \put(726,2192){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}$-0.2$}}%
      \put(726,2630){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}$0$}}%
      \put(726,3067){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}$0.2$}}%
      \put(726,3505){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}$0.4$}}%
      \put(726,3943){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}$0.6$}}%
      \put(726,4381){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}$0.8$}}%
      \put(726,4819){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}$1$}}%
      \put(858,220){\makebox(0,0){\strut{}$-10$}}%
      \put(2344,220){\makebox(0,0){\strut{}$-5$}}%
      \put(3831,220){\makebox(0,0){\strut{}$0$}}%
      \put(5317,220){\makebox(0,0){\strut{}$5$}}%
      \put(6803,220){\makebox(0,0){\strut{}$10$}}%
    }%
    \gplgaddtomacro\gplfronttext{%
      \csname LTb\endcsname%%
      \put(5816,4646){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}$sin(x)$}}%
    }%
    \gplbacktext
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width={360.00bp},height={252.00bp}]{sinus}}%
    \gplfronttext
  \end{picture}%
\endgroup
```

which works. And next is source code for histogram, which does not:

```
% GNUPLOT: LaTeX picture with Postscript
\begingroup
  \makeatletter
  \providecommand\color[2][]{%
    \GenericError{(gnuplot) \space\space\space\@spaces}{%
      Package color not loaded in conjunction with
      terminal option `colourtext'%
    }{See the gnuplot documentation for explanation.%
    }{Either use 'blacktext' in gnuplot or load the package
      color.sty in LaTeX.}%
    \renewcommand\color[2][]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\includegraphics[2][]{%
    \GenericError{(gnuplot) \space\space\space\@spaces}{%
      Package graphicx or graphics not loaded%
    }{See the gnuplot documentation for explanation.%
    }{The gnuplot epslatex terminal needs graphicx.sty or graphics.sty.}%
    \renewcommand\includegraphics[2][]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\rotatebox[2]{#2}%
  \@ifundefined{ifGPcolor}{%
    \newif\ifGPcolor
    \GPcolorfalse
  }{}%
  \@ifundefined{ifGPblacktext}{%
    \newif\ifGPblacktext
    \GPblacktexttrue
  }{}%
  % define a \g@addto@macro without @ in the name:
  \let\gplgaddtomacro\g@addto@macro
  % define empty templates for all commands taking text:
  \gdef\gplbacktext{}%
  \gdef\gplfronttext{}%
  \makeatother
  \ifGPblacktext
    % no textcolor at all
    \def\colorrgb#1{}%
    \def\colorgray#1{}%
  \else
    % gray or color?
    \ifGPcolor
      \def\colorrgb#1{\color[rgb]{#1}}%
      \def\colorgray#1{\color[gray]{#1}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LTw\endcsname{\color{white}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LTb\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LTa\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT0\endcsname{\color[rgb]{1,0,0}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT1\endcsname{\color[rgb]{0,1,0}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT2\endcsname{\color[rgb]{0,0,1}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT3\endcsname{\color[rgb]{1,0,1}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT4\endcsname{\color[rgb]{0,1,1}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT5\endcsname{\color[rgb]{1,1,0}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT6\endcsname{\color[rgb]{0,0,0}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT7\endcsname{\color[rgb]{1,0.3,0}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT8\endcsname{\color[rgb]{0.5,0.5,0.5}}%
    \else
      % gray
      \def\colorrgb#1{\color{black}}%
      \def\colorgray#1{\color[gray]{#1}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LTw\endcsname{\color{white}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LTb\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LTa\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT0\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT1\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT2\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT3\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT4\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT5\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT6\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT7\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT8\endcsname{\color{black}}%
    \fi
  \fi
    \setlength{\unitlength}{0.0500bp}%
    \ifx\gptboxheight\undefined%
      \newlength{\gptboxheight}%
      \newlength{\gptboxwidth}%
      \newsavebox{\gptboxtext}%
    \fi%
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.5pt}%
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{1pt}%
\begin{picture}(7200.00,5040.00)%
    \gplgaddtomacro\gplbacktext{%
      \csname LTb\endcsname%%
      \put(594,440){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}$0$}}%
      \put(594,1316){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}$20$}}%
      \put(594,2192){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}$40$}}%
      \put(594,3067){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}$60$}}%
      \put(594,3943){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}$80$}}%
      \put(594,4819){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}$100$}}%
      \put(1069,220){\makebox(0,0){\strut{}2011}}%
      \put(1411,220){\makebox(0,0){\strut{}2012}}%
      \put(1754,220){\makebox(0,0){\strut{}2013}}%
      \put(2097,220){\makebox(0,0){\strut{}2014}}%
      \put(2440,220){\makebox(0,0){\strut{}2015}}%
      \put(2782,220){\makebox(0,0){\strut{}2016}}%
      \put(3125,220){\makebox(0,0){\strut{}2017}}%
      \put(3468,220){\makebox(0,0){\strut{}2018}}%
      \put(3811,220){\makebox(0,0){\strut{}June2019}}%
      \put(4153,220){\makebox(0,0){\strut{}March2020}}%
    }%
    \gplgaddtomacro\gplfronttext{%
      \csname LTb\endcsname%%
      \put(5615,4489){\makebox(0,0)[l]{\strut{}Urban areas}}%
      \csname LTb\endcsname%%
      \put(5615,4709){\makebox(0,0)[l]{\strut{}Rural areas}}%
    }%
```

I am helpless, trying to find solution for almost 2 days... I also have some screenshots of errors.

[image]

[image]

and this is the histogram:

[image]

**Test file that works**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{xits math}

\begin{document}

\input{sinus}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Test file that does not work**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{xits math}

\begin{document}

\input{plothisto}

\end{document}
```

EDIT:
After adding

```
 \gplbacktext
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width={360.00bp},height={252.00bp}]{sinus}}%
    \gplfronttext
  \end{picture}%
\endgroup
```

to my code, It prints this, though its narrow...

[image]

Comment: please provide a test file that people can debug. The error is shown on a line with `\caption{Histogram}` that does not seem to be in the code you have posted.

Comment: (as the error is in the caption layout it looks to be unrelated to the  gnuplot charts.)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the fact that I only change from `\input{sinus}` to `\input{histogram}` leave me no other choice than in source code of that generated `.tex` file

Comment: I have created test file, will add to edited post.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I needed to try fontspec and Lualatex in particular, but i doesnt matter which font.

Comment: I get `! LaTeX Error: \begin{picture} on input line 82 ended by \end{document}.` if I save the posted code as plothisto.tex and then run your main document?

Comment: there is no end{picture} in the file? (and why do you need fontspec here at all?)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle youre right, there is no \end{picture}. I use fontspec because I use mostly other fonts in my projects and I want to use other fonts in my master thesis as well. When I added the missing lines from sinus file It does work now, Its  not what I have expected, but Its move forward, thank you 

Comment: sure you need fontspec in your original document but if asking people to trace code for you, it helps if you remove everything that is not relevant to the issue.